# How to control microphone output from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, media, microphone, recorder

I am building an app, which needs to record a microphone. I want users to control microphone output from the app, mute/unmute it.

Is it possible ? If yes, how can I achieve that ?

React version of the project

```json
   "react": "^17.0.2",
```

Code where I get an microphono input

```js
const handleRecord = async () => {
    setIsAudioLoading(true);
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: "audio/wav" });
    let orderNumber = 0;
    let chunks = [];

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/wav" });
      streamChunk(blob, orderNumber, "mic");
      chunks = [];
    };

    mediaRecorder.start();

    setStopMic(() => () => {
      setIsMicPaused(true);
      setCurrentAudioTime(lastChunkSecondRef.current - 1.5);
      isMicPausedRef.current = true;
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    });
    setStartMic(() => () => {
      setIsMicPaused(false);
      isMicPausedRef.current = false;
      mediaRecorder.start();
    });

    setInterval(function () {
      if (!isMicPausedRef.current) {
        orderNumber++;
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.start();
      }
    }, MIC_INTERVAL);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mute and unmute your recording by changing the stream track `muted` property like so:

```
let tracks = stream.getAudioTracks();

//muting
tracks.forEach(track => {
  track.muted = true;
});

//unmuting
tracks.forEach(track => {
  track.muted = false;
});
```

You can find more a detailed description of the muted property here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/muted

In case you need to track the muted property, you can listen to `track.onmute` and `track.onunmute` events.
If you need to adjust the volume of your recording aswell, you should take a look into the Web Audio API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Comment: Hey NickG. Thanks for the comment. I implemented the mute/unmute-ing part by changing property 'enabled' on an audioTrack. Do you know how can I controll the volume of the output ? That's the main thing I am trying to find out

Comment: You can adjust the volume by using AudioContext and a gainNode. In this thread is an example on how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43702567/8788847. Just use the destination stream as input for your MediaRecorder.

Comment: Will try. Thanks