# Detect if sound is muted using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am building a webpage that requires sound to operate. I have instructions, but many users do not read them.

I would like to have an alert window pop up telling the user to unmute their volume if and only if their volume is muted, so as not to bother users whose sound is on.

Is this possible to implement in JavaScript (or another language I could use in a webpage)? I know that detecting the state of the sound card is a system thing, so I'm not sure if it's possible to tap into that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26763182/5271890

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Recording the sound output via microphone is also no option as it is often filtered out to prevent feedback loops. You could however add a little test to your website 'press button when you hear sound' o.e.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible. Also take a look at [Javascript: Can you read the systems volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368596/javascript-can-you-read-the-systems-volume)

Comment: @le_m Thanks for the idea, but that is not doable. This is the page in question: http://interlinked.x10host.com/projects/landlines/telcoemulator/ - the UX includes many refreshes of the page that retrieve the code from the server each time, and as such, that would prompt would not make for good UX since they would get it upon each refresh. I would only want it the first time, or not at all. I know many applications are able to do this, but I presume they have much greater access to the system than a webpage. So what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to detect system's volume (sound) and audio jack plugged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149717/javascript-to-detect-systems-volume-sound-and-audio-jack-plugged-in)