# In Web Audio API, how to check if the user's device is muted?

Tags: ios, iphone, html5-audio, progressive-web-apps, web-audio-api

I'd like to know if the sound on a mobile device is muted when using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

Is there a way to know if the mute switch on an iPhone is toggled to off?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://amazingaudioplayer.com/mobile-web-audio-player/volume-control-button-on-iphone-and-ipad/) states that **Javascript cannot control the volume of iOS**. This is confirmed in a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441610/6577242).

Also worth reading: [Overcoming iOS HTML5 audio limitations](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/)

Comment: I'm aware of the limitations. I  was looking for more creative solutions. Like using a microphone or accelerometer to detect if it plays....

Comment: on a side note, the html5 audio tag seems to play even when the iPhone is muted, but the web audio api does not.

Comment: sadly, it doesnt