# How to check mobile environment volume with js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I check the mobile phone volume with javascript in the mobile environment?

For example, if you want to print that your phone volume is 0 when you press a button, is it possible to use js or react?? I am wondering if I need to develop natively.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: Can you read the systems volume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368596/javascript-can-you-read-the-systems-volume)

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about Javascript in a browser environment. In this case, the answer is clear, short and simple: No. The browser disallows your access (via a process called "sandboxing"), not JavaScript.