# How to detect whether the OS muted speaker in the browser?

Tags: html, browser, webrtc

How to detect whether the OS muted speaker in the browser?
I want to detect it while the user can not hear any audio in my webRTC app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlS8I.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGWVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

To check if your browser tab is muted you can use [`tabs.MutedInfo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/MutedInfo).

But on your screenshots there's an OS volume slider, not from browser. You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368617/4755595) get information about your system volume from JS code running in browser.